# Create CSV of Array of Hashes with Different Keys

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

I have an array of hashes that largely contain the same values; but, some of the hashes have additional key value pairs that the others don't.  For example the array looks something like

```
example_array = [{"make" => "nissan", "model" => "altima"}, {"make" => "nissan", "model" => "maxima", "price" => "20,000"}]
```

My issue comes that I'm trying to export this array of hashes into a CSV.  I can't figure out how to

1. Make sure that the headers of the file has a column/key for every possible key that exists in the array
2. Make sure that values end up in the correct column

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what about default values in case if attribute missing?

Comment: I'd just want it to be empty for that value/cell in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like:

```
require 'csv'

headers = example_array.inject([]) {|res, h| h.keys | res} #all possible headers
#=> ["make", "model", "price"]
rows = example_array.map {|h| h.values_at(*headers)}
#=> [["nissan", "altima", nil], ["nissan", "maxima", "20,000"]]
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << headers
  rows.each do |row|
    csv << row
  end
end
```

If you want to write csv in file, just write `CSV.open("myfile.csv", "w")`
instead of `CSV.generate`.